# How to return an ArrayList() from complex method in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question is very simple. Consider the following Angular method:

```
getAllOrdersHeaders(){
    this.getAllOrdersIds().subscribe(idList=>{
      idList.forEach(id=>{
        this.ordersCollection.doc(id).collection('metadata').doc('metadata').get()
        .subscribe(metadata=>{
          console.log(metadata.data());
        });
      })
    });
  }
```

The previous method, go through a list of ids of Firebase documents, in order to find the metainformation of a document.

The question is: How can I return a list of these **metadata objects**, instead of printing them on the console?

Comment: Can you share what you are getting in console?

Answer (score 0):

In short: You can't return these objects in a synchronous way. You can only return them asynchronously by returning a promise of an observable yourself.

Comment: I feel sorry, but I do not understand you very well, you could show me an example in code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> you can use callbacks

```
  let array = [] // global variable

 // declaring callback function outside
 addMetaData = (val) => {
   array.push(val);
  }

// Now use getAllorders function

 getAllOrdersHeaders(callbackFunction){
 this.getAllOrdersIds().subscribe(idList=>{
     idList.forEach(id=>{
        this.ordersCollection.doc(id).collection('metadata').doc('metadata').get()
          .subscribe(metadata=>{
              callbackFunction(metadata.data()); // whenever the data is fetched you are calling the function to store data

       });
     })
   });
} 

 // Now call getAllOrders with callbackFunction ie addMetaData

 getAllOrders(addMetaData);

// the result will be stored in the array variable declared on the top
```